# How to correct this case expression

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following code:

```
select c from(
select 
CASE WHEN EXISTS  (select number, lmn 
  from inma
  WHERE (number='6447' and lmn='ZKZ'))
  then 'yes'
    else 'no' end as c
      from inma )
group by c
```

I have many number and lmn records in the database, that is why I would like when I run the code to see number and lmn and the result 'yes' (if the number and lmn exist) and 'no' (if they do not exist). You can see what I would like to see in the screen shot below.

[image]

How I can do this? I use PL/SQL developer

Thanks for your cooperation in advance.

Comment: what is the problem with your example ? what is not working ?

Comment: Why are you grouping by yes/no if you want to see the number and lmn as well?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see those extra fields, then it seems to me that you can just do this:

```
SELECT
  i.number,
  i.lmn,
  CASE WHEN i.number='6447' AND i.lmn='ZKZ' THEN
    'yes'
  ELSE 
    'no'
  END AS c
FROM
  inma i
```

If number and lmn contain duplicates, and you want to hide that, you can use `SELECT DISTINCT`. You only need to `group by` when you are aggregating (e.g. calculating a sum).